# 1084: Syntax Error: Expecting rightparen before New

Tags: actionscript-3, syntax-error

I started on AS3 before 3 days, and i have written this code, but there's something wrong and i don't know which is the mistake.. Please help or Correct this! Thank you very much!
Regards ValterZHD.

My code

```
var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
var myFont:Font = new (Times New Roman) ();
format.font = myFont.fontName;
message_mc.message_txt.defaultTextFormat = format; 
message_mc.message_txt.text = "You're lost in wilderness";
```

Comment: You're using the font name without quoting it, as if it was an object, which will result in a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks it worked but now in output says "TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.
 at Untitled_4_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()"

Comment: You've used new without providing a constructor. (Times New Roman) is not a constructor. It's not even an object. "Times New Roman" would be a string. Right now, it's treating Times as an object...

Comment: Could you please tell me how to fix that error? Im sorry, im very new at AS3..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no Font class in AS3. You only need to provide the font name to the TextFormat font property.

```
var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

format.font = "Times New Roman";

message_mc.message_txt.defaultTextFormat = format;

message_mc.message_txt.text = "You're lost in wilderness";
```

Comment: My apologies, now it tells me TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
 at Untitled_4_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Comment: Do you have a MovieClip instance with the id message_mc and within it a TextField with the id message_txt?